# php preg_replace assign different replacement pattern for each capturing group

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, sql-injection, capturing-group

I'm trying to perform a mysql fulltext search in boolean mode and I need to prepare the search text before I build the mysql query.

In order to achieve it, I though I could use the PHP function `preg_replace` and replace each capturing group by one specific pattern.

1. First pattern must find words or sentences between quotes (`"hello world"`) and add a `+` before (`+"hello world"`).
2. Second pattern must find the rest of words (without quotes) and add a `+` before and a `*` after (`+how*`).

**regex pattern**

```
["']+([^"']+)["']+|([^\s"']+)
```

**substitution pattern**

```
+"\1" +\2*
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

For the following input:

```
"hello world" how are you?
```

It should return:

```
+"hello world" +how* +are* +you?*
```

But instead, it returns **something 'wrong'**:

```
+"hello world" +* +"" +how* +"" +are* +"" +you?*
```

I'm aware that the replacement pattern `+"\1" +\2*` will never work since I'm not telling anywhere that `+"..."` should only apply to the first capturing group and `+...*` to the second one.

[Test online regex](https://regex101.com/r/iBzKHu/1).

**PHP code**

```
$query = preg_replace('~["\']+([^"\']+)["\']+|([^\s"\']+)~', '+"\1" +\2*', $query);
```

Is there a way to achieve this in PHP? Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT / SOLUTION**

Thanks to [@revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) suggestion to use the PHP function [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), I managed to assign a replace pattern to each search pattern with the extended function [`preg_replace_callback_array`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback_array). Please note that this function needs PHP >= 7.

Here I post the final version of the function I use to perform a `FULLTEXT` search via `MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) IN BOOLEAN MODE`. The function is declared within the `class dbReader` in a Wordpress Plugin. Maybe it can be useful for someone.

```
// Return maximum 100 ids of products matching $query in
// name or description searching for each word using MATCH AGAINST in BOOLEAN MODE
public function search_products($query) {

    function replace_callback($m, $f) {
        return sprintf($f, isset($m[1]) ? $m[1] : $m[0]);
    }

    // Replace simple quotes by double quotes in strings between quotes:
    // iPhone '8 GB' => iPhone "8 GB"
    // Apple's iPhone 8 '32 GB' => Apple's iPhone 8 "32 GB"
    // This is necessary later when the matches are devided in two groups:
    //      1. Strings not between double quotes
    //      2. Strings between double quotes
    $query = preg_replace("~(\s*)'+([^']+)'+(\s*)~", '$1"$2"$3', $query);

    // Do some magic to take numbers with their units as one word
    // iPhone 8 64 GB => iPhone 8 "64 GB"
    $pattern = array(
        '(\b[.,0-9]+)\s*(gb\b)',
        '(\b[.,0-9]+)\s*(mb\b)',
        '(\b[.,0-9]+)\s*(mm\b)',
        '(\b[.,0-9]+)\s*(mhz\b)',
        '(\b[.,0-9]+)\s*(ghz\b)'
    );
    array_walk($pattern, function(&$value) {
        // Surround with double quotes only if the user isn't doing manual grouping
        $value = '~'.$value.'(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)~i';
    });
    $query = preg_replace($pattern, '"$1 $2"', $query);

    // Prepare query string for a "match against" in "boolean mode"
    $patterns = array(
        // 1. All strings not sorrounded by double quotes
        '~([^\s"]+)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)~'   => function($m){
            return replace_callback($m, '+%s*');
        },

        // 2. All strings between double quotes
        '~"+([^"]+)"+~'                             => function($m){
            return replace_callback($m, '+"%s"');
        }
    );

    // Replace every single word by a boolean expression: +some* +word*
    // Respect quoted strings: +"iPhone 8"
    // preg_replace_callback_array needs PHP Version >= 7
    $query = preg_replace_callback_array($patterns, $query);

    $fulltext_fields = array(
        'title'         => array(
            'importance'    => 1.5,
            'table'         => 'p',
            'fields'        => array(
                'field1',
                'field2',
                'field3',
                'field4'
            )
        ),
        'description'   => array(
            'importance'    => 1,
            'table'         => 'p',
            'fields'        => array(
                'field5',
                'field6',
                'field7',
                'field8'
            )
        )
    );
    $select_match = $match_full = $priority_order = "";

    $args = array();
    foreach ($fulltext_fields as $index => $obj) {
        $match          = $obj['table'].".".implode(", ".$obj['table'].".", $obj['fields']);
        $select_match  .= ", MATCH ($match) AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS {$index}_score";
        $match_full    .= ($match_full!=""?", ":"").$match;
        $priority_order.= ($priority_order==""?"ORDER BY ":" + ")."({$index}_score * {$obj['importance']})";
        array_push($args, $query);
    }
    $priority_order .= $priority_order!=""?" DESC":"";

    // User input $query is passed as %s parameter to db->prepare() in order to avoid SQL injection
    array_push($args, $query, $this->model_name, $this->view_name);

    return $this->db->get_col(
        $this->db->prepare(
            "SELECT p.__pk $select_match
            FROM ankauf_... AND
                    MATCH ($match_full) AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                INNER JOIN ...
            WHERE
                m.bezeichnung=%s AND
                a.bezeichnung=%s
                $priority_order
            LIMIT 100
            ;",
            $args
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You need `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Now I'd like to be sure that **this query does not remain open to MySQL injection**.
Do you think it's enough `db->prepare("... AGAINST (%s IN BOOLEAN MODE) ...")` to avoid it?
Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Using prepared statements properly, yes it would be safe.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll consider the code as concluded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$str = '"hello world" how are you?';

echo preg_replace_callback('~("[^"]+")|\S+~', function($m) {
    return isset($m[1]) ? "+" . $m[1] : "+" . $m[0] . "*";
}, $str);
```

Output:

```
+"hello world" +how* +are* +you?*
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/Y48CQ)

Comment: I accepted your answer but I couldn't mark it as 'useful' (up vote) because I need at least 15 reputation points.